# Shift in time series prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series

I was looking at many time-series predictions at google image [(such as these ones)](https://www.google.com/search?q=time%20series&rlz=1C5CHFA_enCA867CA868&sxsrf=ACYBGNTEwENOGbBpiRaYyvZXoNBoJDWmBA:1576506855140&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJrtjYsbrmAhVKQq0KHc2eAgoQ_AUoAXoECGwQAw&biw=1450&bih=1162) and I noticed a regular shift in predicted vs actual values. A naive thing that comes to mind is to shift back the predicted curve to have better results. Is this ok to do?

for example, please look at the following figure, 
[image: A time-series example showing a shift in predicted vs actual quantities]

Comment: Are you using past predictions to predict the current, (ie. you have to use x(0) to predict for x(1)), because then you will never have a prediction for x(0), hence the lag of -1.

Comment: I am using the past observed to predict the next observation.

Comment: Yes, so you will never have a prediction for x(0), which means you have to offset your predicted array by +1. If you are using matplotlib, you should do something like:      plot(range(1,len(x)+1),x)

Comment: Sorry, I mean plt.plot(...) !